# Is $L'L_\text{in}+L_\text{in}'L$ positive semi-definite? $L$ and $L_\text{in}$ are graph Laplacian matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, positive-definite

Assume that $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a strongly connected directed graph, that is, $A$ is non-negative and irreducible. Let $$L_\text{in}=D_\text{in}-A',\;L=D_\text{in}-A'+D_\text{out}-A$$ where $D_\text{in}$ and $D_\text{out}$ are the in and out degree matrix, respectively. i.e. $$D_\text{in}=\text{diag}(A'\mathbb{1}),\; D_\text{out}=\text{diag}(A\mathbb{1})$$
where $\mathbb{1}$ is a vector with all elements be 1 and diag() is the Matlab function diag(). I wonder if the matrix $$M = L'L_\text{in}+L_\text{in}'L$$ is positive semi-definite?

I have tried several $A$ using Matlab and the results are all positive semi-definite, so I think it is true. Actually, $L$ is positive semi-definite and each eigenvalue of $L_\text{in}$ has a positive real part. Besides, both $L$ and $L_\text{in}$ have zero row sums. Is there any suggestion for a proof or a counterexample? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, one question, since I'm not too familiarized with graph theory. If the graph is undirected, then A is symmetric. If it's strongly connected, do you know something additional about A? Thanks!

Comment: @NicoF. As far as I know, the directed graph is strongly connected if and only if $A$ is irreducible. Then I know two equivalent definitions of a irreducible matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ from [here](http://motion.me.ucsb.edu/book-lns/), 1) $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k>0$, where $>$ is element-wise here. 2) there exists no permutation matrix $P$ such that $P'AP$ is block triangular.